# In Event receiver property BeforeProperties is empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I'm developing an event receiver for Item Updated in a list.
But when I debug the code `BeforeProperties` is empty.

Here is the code:

```
string afterValue = properties.AfterProperties["ExpectedDateOfFulfill"].ToString();

string beforeValue = properties.BeforeProperties["ExpectedDateOfFulfill"].ToString();

if (beforeValue != afterValue) {}
```

Any ideas why the property is empty?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
Event receiver should be ItemUpdating and the code should be like this:

```
string afterValue = properties.AfterProperties["ExpectedDateOfFulfill"].ToString();

string beforeValue =  properties.ListItem["ExpectedDateOfFulfill"].ToString();
```